# PhpStorm Expression Expected Using PHP Short Echo Tags Inside HTML Attributes

Tags: php, html, phpstorm

I found something similar to this while doing a code review, and I don't see what is wrong with the code (shown as a syntax error by PhpStorm). The problem is using PHP short echo tags in an HTML attribute. PhpStorm doesn't seem to have a problem with the usage in the label's for attribute, or the input's id attribute, but indicates there is an error in the input's name attribute. Here is a simple way to replicate.

Filename: trash.phtml

```
<?php
/** ...*/
function getId(): string
{
    return '0';
}
?>
<label for="bundle_me[<?= getId(); ?>]"></label>
<input type="hidden"
       id="bundle_me[<?= getId(); ?>]"
       name="bundle_me[<?= getId(); ?>]"/>
```

This is PhpStorm 2021.1.4 running on a Linux VM.
PHP version 7.4

[image: Screenshot of PhpStorm's code detection having a problem with the name attribute.]

Comment: You don't put `;` at the end when using the short echo tags.

Comment: @Barmar: You should not, but you can. It's (at least) possible. `<?=`  is short for `<?php echo ` and not requiring the `;` terminator.

Comment: The inconsistency seems like a PhpStorm bug -- it sometimes gets confused like this. Does removing the `;` clear it up?

Comment: Invalidate caches and restart. Otherwise: install EA-Inspections plugin for your PHP code-reviews. It gives the hint about removing the semicolon right away ;).

Comment: Looks more like a bug report.

Comment: @Barmar removeing the ```;``` did not clear it up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a bug in the Angular plugin: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-39052
Has to be fixed by the WebStorm team. In the meanwhile, you can disable the plugin if you are not using Angular.

Comment: Disabling the 'Angular and AngularJS' plugin resolved this for me.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your screenshot -- the name attribute value has different (light green) background... which tells that you have somehow injected another language there.

1. `Settings/Preferences | Editor | Language Injections`
2. Look at all entries there where `Scope` column has "IDE" or "Project" values.
3. Locate and disable unexpected rule (most likely will be HTML or XML + `name` and/or `input` mentioned)
4. If all good -- you can now delete that wrong rule.

   - If not sure: post that screen with IDE & Project scope rows.
5. If still nothing -- could be some plugin (AFAIK bundled Angular plugin has similar kind of issues...)